# Rotating a Matrix clockwise in c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to rotate a multi-dimensional array clockwise.

Here's my code.

I've already got the transpose part down but I need help with the reverse section.

I've tried multiple solution but they just don't work with the code I already have so, yeah. Thank you.

Desired output

```
7 4 1
8 5 2
9 6 3
```

```
static void RotateMatrix()
{
    // Multidimenonsal array to rotate
    int[,] matrix = new int[,] 
    {
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6},
    {7, 8, 9}
    };

    // Swaps places -- transpose
    /*
    Output of this for loop
    {
    1 4 7
    2 5 8
    3 6 9
    }
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
        {

            var temp = matrix[i, j]; // store matrix(pos x, pos y) in temp var
            matrix[i, j] = matrix[j, i]; // set the position matrix(pos x, pos y) to (opposite position)
            matrix[j, i] = temp; // set (opposite position) to temp var

           
        }

    }

    // Reverse !! Need help Here!!

    
    // Prints out the rotated matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(matrix[j, i]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

    }

}
```

Comment: So you want to reverse the transposition of the matrix (no idea why you call it "rotate")? Just do the same again - transposition is its own inverse.

Comment: If this is not what you want to do, please describe in more detail what you mean by "rotate" - listing the desired output would be one way to do this.

Comment: I'm trying to rotate the matrix clockwise 90 degrees. I forgot to add that my bad.

Comment: @KlausGütter I've updated the post. What I'm trying to do is rotate the multi-dimensional array clockwise. I've updated the post with the desired output and where I'm stuck and why I need to reverse it.

Comment: Aha. So your second operation would be to mirror the columns `matrix[i, j] = matrix[i, N - 1 - j]`

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inplace-rotate-square-matrix-by-90-degrees/

Comment: Your code and your description of what you want don't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rotating a matrix in place will be quite challenging. I would highly recommend just creating a new matrix, especially when dealing with small matrices. You will also need to reverse the direction in one of the index operations:

```
    var result = new int[3,3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            result[j, 2-i] = matrix[i, j]; 
        }
    }
```

However, unless you are doing this for learning I would suggest using a pre-existing matrix library, it will likely both have more features and be faster.

For example, you made one of the classic blunders when working with multidimensional matrices and call `matrix.GetLength(...)` for each iteration, this method is fairly slow, so you should be getting the length outside the loop and storing it.